# Sending an array through form in hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to send an array from an html page to an asp proxy (to a service), but cannot get the array to work properly.

Array Type: json

Scripting: JavaScript/jquery

```
var order = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
if (list[i].included == true)
order.push({ MarketID: list[i].marketID, Crop: list[i].crop })
}

$("#orderValue").val(order.join());
...

<form action="/hd.asp" method="post" id="hdForm">
<input type="hidden" name="order" id="orderValue" />
...
</form>
```

Removing the array, it works properly, but the array is required property. I have tried just sending array, using .join(), and few other  things, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can you show the code where you serialize the array and assign it to the field?

Comment: Try an `alert(order)` right before you try and set the val to make sure `order` is actually an array with some stuff in it. Otherwise, please elaborate on what you mean by nothing seems to be working. The form isn't submitting? There is no value for #orderValue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] c.hill got there first :$ [/EDIT]

Don't use `join()`, use `JSON.stringify()`, e.g.:

```
var doit = function( myArray ) {
    var arrayString = JSON.stringify( myArray );
    $('#orderValue').val( arrayString );
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(order) doesn't work either, example of what array looks like after use: order=%5B%7B%22MarketID%22%3A1352%2C%22Crop%22%3A4%7D%2C%7B%22MarketID%22..repea‌​ting

Comment: It looks URLEncoded. Try decoding it - there's a function if you need it [Here](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-decode-an-encoded-url.html)

Comment: JSON.stringify() was the correct answer, I had another issue in the asp that was preventing the flow to the wcf service, but this answer fixed the first part and let me find the second part and get it all working, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#orderValue").val(JSON.stringify(order));
```

**Edit**.. Oops, should have put order inside of JSON.stringify() as an argument. Try it now.

Comment: you should add the link to the JSON library that has stringify in it as OP will need to add this script. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: No need - JSON is a subset of Javascript. No link required.

Comment: JSON.stringify(order) doesn't work either, example of what array looks like after use: order=%5B%7B%22MarketID%22%3A1352%2C%22Crop%22%3A4%7D%2C%7B%22MarketID%22..repeating

Comment: Hmmm... what's the output of console.log($("#orderValue").val()); after attempting to set the value of the hidden field?